# stuck getting GNOME Classic as default

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome

I am trying to set up GNOME Classic (on Ubuntu 12.04.1) to be my default desktop, I can install it without issue and I know how to change to it at the login screen.

The problem I have is when I reboot, the login screen defaults back to Unity for login, is there away to set GNOME Classic to be the default (without removing unity)?

I have installed and configuring as follows but it always defaults to unity

```
apt-get install gnome-session-fallback indicator-applet-appmenu gnome-tweak-tool
```

and enable

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults -s gnome-classic
```

Also have the following in  */etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf*

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=gnome-classic
greeter-session=unity-greeter
greeter-show-manual-login = true
allow-guest=false
```

Answer (score 1):

It's so strange that what you have done didn't solve your problem since it must do that.

Anyway you can try to edit the `.dmrc` in your home.It looks like

```
[Desktop]
Session=ubuntu
```

For GNOME Classic you can change it to say:

```
[Desktop]
Session=gnome-classic
```